# How do you get VLC to show folders first then files when sorting by name in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, ubuntu-22.04

When I try to sort files and folders in ascending order in VLC on Ubuntu 22.04, for some reason it shows the folders after the file names. If I sort in descending order it shows the folders first, but all the names are in descending order.